# What are Modules when creating COM objects with Embarcadero C++ Buider

Tags: com, module, c++builder

I am creating a COM library with Embarcadero C++ Builder.  The designer for the ridl file gives several things you can add to the ridl.  I think I understand all of them except for creating new "Modules".  I can't find good information for it in the documentation.

What is  a "Module" and what would it be used for in COM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *module* attribute is described in this [MSDN Library page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367099%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  It permits declaring entrypoints in a DLL.  That has little to do with COM, it is just a capability of a type library.  You'll find few language development environments that can use them.  I think VB6 was one of them.  Ymmv.

Answer (score 2):

**You say you can't find 'good information' in the documentation; what have you found?**  The [RAD Studio help has a section specifically explaining modules](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Library_Elements#Modules), which says:

> A module defines a group of functions,
>   typically a set of DLL entry points.
>   You define a module by
>
> - Specifying a DLL that it represents on the attributes page.
> - Adding methods and constants using the toolbar or the object list pane
>     context menu. For each method or
>     constant, you must then define its
>     attributes by selecting the it in the
>     object list pane and setting the
>     values on the Attributes page.
>
> For module methods, you must assign a
>   name and DLL entry point using the
>   attributes page. Declare the
>   function's parameters and return type
>   using the parameters page.
>
> For module constants, use the
>   Attributes page to specify a name,
>   type, and value.
>
> Note: The Type Library Editor does not generate any declarations or
>   implementation related to a module.
>   The specified DLL must be created as a
>   separate project.

It seems it's specifying methods that exist in an external DLL to whatever module (EXE or DLL) the type library is built into.  Exactly what that's used for... is a good question.

Comment: I probably should have included this reference from the documentation, but I don't understand what it means.  How would this be used and how is it useful?